# Creating a Unity VR app for Mixed Reality and Windows 10 Universal

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-10-universal, windows-mixed-reality

I created a Unity, Windows 10 Universal project, with VR enabled, using a 2d template, and the only scene consists of a cube on either side of the screen. I set up the cameras so that I had a left and right for each lens, with each cube applied appropriately to its respective lens via layers. When I launch it in Mixed reality, it appears in a pinnable window but only the right cube is visible. I tried the same project for PC and both cubes appear in their respective eyes.

Did I do something wrong or is this not possible? It's the only way I can think of getting a true 3d SBS pinnable video player into the cliff House.

Comment: Why you choose 2d template as your template?

Comment: No specific reason other than wanting the app to appear in 2D mode in Mixed reality and not full screen immersive mode. Not that it seems to matter. 2D template in Unity still renders 3D so it's not the issue.

Comment: There seems to be no way to target specific eye cameras for apps in Cliff house which is a major limitation. You can't even watch a 3D film pinned to the wall.